# Winforms how do I set datagridviewtextboxcolumn's text?

Tags: winforms, text, datagridview

Hello I am using winforms and I was wondering..
How do I set a datagridviewtextboxcolumn's text without binding it to a object?

I don't see a text property for the DataGridViewTextBoxColumn type in the designer, and I don't know how to set it in code.

I have tried messing with the name properties but that doesn't seem to do anything.

## EDIT: this question was poorly thought out

the original question was supposed to be how do I set the text of a datagridviewtextboxcolumn in the designer without code.

I don't think this is possible because you can't add rows to it from the designer. but only a template row.

I am sincerely sorry for wasting your time I will accept the closest answer to the question and will try to make better questions in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each `Cell` has a `Row` index and `Column` index and you can change them using `Value`
property. for example:

```
private void DgvExample()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; j++)
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value = "index: [" + i.ToString() + "," + j.ToString() + "]";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: so I'm guessing this isn't possible in the designer? What event would I use for something like this?

Comment: sorry I am exploring winforms and I had multiple intentions at the time. I didn't realize you can't really add new rows from the designer and name thier columns. I have recently solved this by using code and from help from your guys.

Answer (score 0):

When you drag and drop the DataGridView on your winform, you can click on the right arrow at the top of the DataGridView, and you should see DataGridView Tasks where you can select to add a column, and you can set the header text to whatever you want.

[image: DataGridView]

Comment: this doesn't seem to work for already existing cells. and there is no Name Property in the Edit Column Dialog. Also I Realized What I want to edit is the value of the datagridviewtextbox not the header name. is there a way to do this in the designer?